# Issue with Test Class for REST API

Tags: apex, lightning, unit-test, rest-api, controller

I have an apex class which fetches and upserts data from external source to Salesforce.

Below is the batch class:

```
global class PolicyCalloutBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<Integer>,Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
 global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
       Integer[] values = new Integer[0];
while(values.size() < 2999) {
    values.add(values.size());
}
return Test.isRunningTest() ? new Integer[1] : values ;
}
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Integer[] values) {
        
        HttpRequest policyreq = new HttpRequest();
        policyreq.setMethod('GET');
        policyreq.setTimeout(120000);
        policyreq.setEndpoint('<endpoint>');
        policyreq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + <token>);
        Http policyhttp = new Http();
        HTTPResponse policyres = policyhttp.send(policyreq);
        String policyresponse = policyres.getBody();
        JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(policyresponse, JsonParser.class);  
        
        JsonParser.cls_value clsValue = objJsonParser.value;
        Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data> clsDataMap = new Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data>();
        for(JsonParser.cls_data objClsData: clsValue.data){
            clsDataMap.put(objClsData.id, objClsData);
        }
        list<Policy__c> updatelist = new list<Policy__c>();
        for (String eachIdFromMap : clsDataMap.keySet()){
            
            Policy__c policy = new Policy__c(
                unique_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).id,
                agent_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).agentId);
            updatelist.add(policy);  
        }
        try{
            upsert updatelist unique_id__c;    
        }
        catch(DmlException e){
            system.debug('This class didnt compile');
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        
    }
}
```

Below is my Mock test class:

```
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        String jsonbody = '{ ' +
              '"id": "11111"' +
              '}' ; 
        HttpResponse objHttpResponse = new HttpResponse();
        objHttpResponse.setBody(jsonbody);
        objHttpResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        objHttpResponse.setStatusCode(200);
        return objHttpResponse;
    }
}
```

Below is my test class:

```
  @isTest 
private class PolicyUpdateController_Test {
    static testMethod void testPostCallout() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());  
        
        Test.startTest();
        PolicyCalloutBatchClass  obj = new PolicyCalloutBatchClass ();
        Database.executeBatch(obj, 50); 
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

Though I am not seeing any errors in my code, my batch apex class is covered only 8%. Complete execute method is left uncovered.

Can anyone please suggest the changes to my above test class so that I can get this done.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test run for Web Service Callout batch class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327558/test-run-for-web-service-callout-batch-class)

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327558/test-run-for-web-service-callout-batch-class/327560#327560

Comment: Earlier the issue was due to test class running in Infinite loop which was resolved. But even though I have updated the test class as per API documentation, I could see that the class is covered only 8%. That's the reason why I came here for suggestion!

Comment: I still see this line `while(values.size() < 2999 || Test.isRunningTest()) values.add(values.size());` which is incorrect. please check the solution in the above link.

Comment: Yes @Nagendra. I have corrected that. But the code coverage is not getting increased beyond 8% and execute method is left uncovered completely.

Comment: @NagendraSingh, could you please suggest on how to pass Integer[] values in test class argument obj.execute()?

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous post. Correct in both plates now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116843/discussion-between-sfdcuser-and-nagendra-singh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you start to this and it should work as it has to add values in `array` before passing that to execute method. So here if test is running we clear the array and add 1 so that the execute gets called at least once.

```
global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    Integer[] values = new Integer[0];
    while(values.size() < 2999) {
        values.add(values.size());
    }
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
        values.clear();
        values.add(1);
    }

    return values ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NarendraSingh. I need one small suggestion pls...I am getting null pointer exception in the line **policyreq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + <token>)**. In real time scenario, this line is working and I could able to see the response successfully where as in test class, it is failing. Could you please suggest any changes here?

Comment: For token you can do something like this:

    `String token = //Get your token from anywhere and assign it to token variable.`
Then do : 

    `token = Test.isRunningTest()  ? '' : token;`

So that your you can assign any dummy variable to token parameter. Or If you fetching the token from DB, just create the same record on Test class to fetch the token from DB.

Comment: Thanks @Narendra.